# ssh tunnel to access file locally

Tags: ssh

Client: Mac OSX 10.9

NAS Server: Debian (Lenny linux)

I have mp3 files on my NAS which I want to play them from my desktop but using mpg321 (on my desktop). I can access my NAS via ssh.

I tried two different method, here I'm using smb port 445 on my remote server (Debian)

```
 ssh -f name@192.168.0.4 -L 15549:127.0.0.1:445 sleep 6000
```

and on a new terminal tab (OSX)

```
 ssh -v localhost -p 15549
```

It works without giving me any error, but how can I access my files? I was also trying to connect via smb from finder smb://localhost:15549/ but this doesn't work

the following which ends on "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" May be I don't understand very well.

```
 ssh -ND 8080 name@192.168.0.4
```

or

```
 ssh -v localhost -p 8080
```

this gave me the problem

```
 OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
  debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
  debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
  debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 8080.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
  debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
  ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I was googling to fix this error but no luck, here are few that I tried

```
   echo 'SSHD: ALL' >> /etc/hosts.allow
   chmod -R 755 /var/
   remove hosts.deny
```

still no luck

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your nas dosen't natively support smb (granted, there's no reason it shouldn't), sshfs or fish would in general be your best bet here.

[The source is a *little* unusual](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/acts/2013/11/08/the-newbie-how-to-set-up-sshfs-on-mac-os-x/) but according to it fuse for OS X would let you use SSHFS. [You can get both packages on their website](http://osxfuse.github.io/). Then its a matter of creating a local mountpoint and mounting it with the right commands

```
sshfs -p 22 username@remoteserver:/source_on_remote_system/ ~/mountpoint_on_local_system -oauto_cache,reconnect,defer_permissions,noappledouble,negative_vncache,volname=myVolName
```

ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

Smb is a complex protocol that I think is hard to get to work over ssh.

An implementation of sshfs might solve your problem. For Windows I found this suggestion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741207/whats-the-best-free-windows-software-to-mount-drive-over-ssh